# How to draw slanting arrows between columns of a table?

Tags: tables, arrows

I'd like to draw some simple slanting arrows between cells in a table.
The two cells can be in almost any position in the table.

For example given this table:

[image: Table without arrows]

How can I modify it to obtain:

[image: Table with arrows]

Another example with also vertical arrows:

[image: Table with also vertical arrows]

Ideally I'd like to avoid using Tikz, since using `tabular` is pretty straightforward to draw this kind of diagrams, but if nothing else can be done then I'll accept a Tikz solution.

The MWE code for the table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
\begin{tabular}{cccccccc}
((\textbf{N}   & $\Rightarrow$ & \textbf{N}) & $\Rightarrow$ & \textbf{N})& $\Longrightarrow$ & \textbf{N} &     \\
               &               &             &               &            &                   &     $q$      & $O$ \\
               &               &             &               &    $q$     &                   &              & $P$ \\
               &               &     $q$     &               &            &                   &              & $O$ \\
               &               &             &               &    $q$     &                   &              & $P$ \\
               &               &     $q$     &               &            &                   &              & $O$ \\
       $q$     &               &             &               &            &                   &              & $P$ \\
               &               &             &    $\vdots$   &            &                   &              &     \\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `\xymatrix` from the [`xypic`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/xypic) package (for a proper introduction to its use, see the excellent [XY-pic User’s Guide](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/generic/diagrams/xypic/doc/xyguide.pdf)).
The `\ar[d]` command typesets arrows in the direction specified as optional argument, so `\ar[r]` moves one cell to the right, `\ar[ur]` moves one up and one right etc.
You can use `\ar@2{->}[r]` for double arrows and `\ar@2/^/[u]` and `\ar@2/_/[u]` for curved arrows.

The first version uses code very similar to your table, the second one replaces all the `\Rightarrow`s by `xy`'s arrows and the third one showcases the use of slanted arrows.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix@=2pt{
((\textbf{N} & \Rightarrow & \textbf{N}) & \Rightarrow & \textbf{N})  & \Longrightarrow & \textbf{N} &  \\
             &             &             &             &              &                 &    q       & O\\
             &             &             &             &  q \ar[urr]  &                 &            & P\\
             &             & q \ar[urr]  &             &              &                 &            & O\\
             &             &             &             & q \ar[uuurr] &                 &            & P\\
             &             &  q \ar[urr] &             &              &                 &            & O\\
  q \ar[urr] &             &             &             &              &                 &            & P\\
             &             &             &    \vdots   &              &                 &            & }

\xymatrix@R=2pt{
((\textbf{N} \ar@2{->}[r] & \textbf{N}) \ar@2{->}[r] & \textbf{N}) \ar@2{->}[r] & \textbf{N} &  \\
                          &                          &                          &     q      & O\\
                          &                          &        q \ar[ur]         &            & P\\
                          &       q \ar[ur]          &                          &            & O\\
                          &                          &       q \ar[uuur]        &            & P\\
                          &       q \ar[ur]          &                          &            & O\\
          q \ar[ur]       &                          &                          &            & P\\
                          &        \vdots            &                          &            & }

\xymatrix@R=2pt{
(\textbf{N} \ar@2{->}[r] & \textbf{N} \ar@2{->}[r] & \textbf{N}) \ar@2{->}[r] & \textbf{N} \\
                         &                         &                          &     q      \\
                         &                         &        q \ar[ur]         &            \\
         q \ar[urr]      &                         &                          &            \\
        \ar@/^1pc/[u]0   &       q \ar[uur]        &                          &            \\
                         &      \ar@/^1pc/[u]1     &                          &            \\
                         &                         &          n\ar[uuuu]      &            \\
                         &                         &                          & n\ar[uuuuuu]}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### EDIT

Centering `xy`diagrams is easy enough, you can either wrap the `xymatrix` in a display math environment with `\[.....\]` (alternative `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}` or whatever fits your needs) or you can wrap it in `\centerline{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[all]{xy}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centerline{\xymatrix@R=2pt{
((\textbf{N} \ar@2{->}[r] & \textbf{N}) \ar@2{->}[r] & \textbf{N}) \ar@2{->}[r] & \textbf{N} &   \\
                          &                          &                          &     q      & O \\
                          &                          &        q \ar[ur]         &            & P \\
                          &       q \ar[ur]          &                          &            & O \\
                          &                          &       q \ar[uuur]        &            & P \\
                          &       q \ar[ur]          &                          &            & O \\
          q \ar[ur]       &                          &                          &            & P \\
                          &        \vdots            &                          &            & }}
\caption{A very interesting diagram with \texttt{centerline}}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
  \[
  \xymatrix@R=2pt{
  (\textbf{N} \ar@2{->}[r] & \textbf{N} \ar@2{->}[r] & \textbf{N}) \ar@2{->}[r] & \textbf{N} \\
                            &                         &                          &     q     \\
                            &                         &        q \ar[ur]         &           \\
            q \ar[urr]      &                         &                          &           \\
           \ar@/^1pc/[u]0   &       q \ar[uur]        &                          &           \\
                            &      \ar@/^1pc/[u]1     &                          &           \\
                            &                         &          n\ar[uuuu]      &           \\
                            &                         &                          & n\ar[uuuuuu]}
  \]
  \caption{A very interesting diagram with displaymath}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

---

For different length arrows you can use `\Rightarrow` and `\Longrightarrow` see the first example. `xypic`'s `xymatrix` draws arrows between cells in a matrix, so to get arrows of different length, you will needs cells that are further apart (this is achieved by empty cells) this will move around the rest of the diagram though.

Comment: I have a problem with this solution: if I put the `xymatrix` inside a `figure` environment the `\centering` doesn't have any effect. The caption is placed at the center, but the diagram is flushed left. Is this a known issue?

Comment: Another request if possible: how can I draw arrows of different lenghts? In your last two examples I'd like the double arrows inside the parenthesis to be shorter then the one outside, *without* changing the spacing between other elements of the diagram, if possible.

Comment: @Bakuriu `xymatrix` is originally a package for commutative diagrams; if you want something fancier, you might want to have a look at TikZ and PGF. You will then have to trade in the "comfort" of `xymatrix`' almost "table"-like structure for something slightly more complicated.